# ImportXML Google Spreadsheet - can't get xml data

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I can't seem to get this very simple example to import anything into Google Spreadsheets:

```
=ImportXML("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml","/note/to")
```

Tried different xml path arguments, but always get an 'analyzing error' and never a value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sign in the formula from "," to ";;"

`=ImportXML("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml";"/note/to")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two slashed in your xpath:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml","//note")
```

Comment: Actually, one slash works, but the simple , vs ; separator was the prob.